# Image library with advanced text effects?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What would be the best Python library to use when producing text-based images requiring things such as leading, kerning, outlines, drop-shadows, etc?

I've worked with PIL before for resizing images, but the methods for working with text seem rather limited. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want to do is exactly what LaTeX was designed for. With [plasTeX](http://plastex.sourceforge.net/plastex/index.html), you can convert LaTeX markup to an image. Here's an example of what you can do with this (from the plasTeX documentation) [image: http://plastex.sourceforge.net/plastex/images/img-0001.png]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://plastex.sourceforge.net/plastex/images/img-0001.png))</sub>
.

Notice the shadows and text effects.

Answer (score 0):

[Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) is very capable, and there are [Python bindings](http://www.cairographics.org/pycairo/) to Cairo. Though, when I used it, I had to look into C documentation too.